# Trying to write a form validation which verifies that all fields total 100

Tags: php, mysql, forms, html

I have a PHP form which lists all the people who will share the cost of an item. Next to each person, there is a blank field which you type the percentage of ownership. Currently, I have no mechanism to prevent you from allocating more than or less than 100%. For example:

```
Joe  - 40%
Jill - 40%
Jane - 40%
```

The above scenario is currently possible and will break the math. Before submitting the form, I would like to verify that the entered percentages total 100. It would be nice if I could do this in real time (before submitting) but upon submit is okay too.

These values get entered into a MySQL DB.

Thank you!

Comment: I would also like to add that the number of people could vary. It could be 1, it could be 37.

Comment: Your going to want to use JavaScript to do this in the browser

Answer (score 1):

Here is a javascript demo I made for you:

- http://jonathancross.com/projects/form-validation.html

Code is not 100% complete, but should get you most of the way there.  Would suggest adding support for up and down arrows on keyboard and of course a submit button  :-)

Note about validation:
You will **also** need to validate the values on the server-side (php) to be sure they work before storing in the database.  Javascript is great for immediate feedback, but is easy to circumvent (if someone wanted to break your app).  It is also possible that users might disable javascript or use a browser which does not support it so beware and always validate on the server side.